# Why Eclipse PDT Explorer shows sub folder not sorted while PDT Navigator shows it sorted properly?

Tags: eclipse

[image]

Can someone please clarify what am I missing? Is this a known bug in Eclipse?

I use latest Luna version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The various **Explorer** views in Eclipse are *logical* representations of projects and their contents. The **Navigator** is a more direct representation of the physical file system. Sorting of the direct file system view is straightforward: sort files and folders by name. Sorting for logical views is much more tricky because the nodes in that tree are logical and heterogenous.

[Here is an open bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=356629) about the sorting specifically in **PHP Explorer**.

Comment: OK. So I should just use the Navigator when working with Eclipse. Correct?

Comment: That depends on what you want/need. Eclipse offers lots of different views because they meet different needs. For example, for Java development I switch frequently between Package Explorer, Navigator, and the various views in the Java Browsing perspective. I don't do PHP but I'm pretty sure PHP Explorer provides features designed to make PHP development better. If alphabetic sorting of folders is the most important feature of the IDE for you, then I guess Navigator is fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for this based [on the comment](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=356629#c19) from the bug report:

1. Go to your project folder and make a backup of .buildpath file
2. Right click project and go to Properties
3. Select Build Path on the left
4. Select all folders there and click Remove
5. Click Add folder, select root folder (project folder) and click Ok